# Why am i not able to get Extras from the intent this way?

Tags: android, android-intent, extra

In the previous Activity i did this:

```
int entryId = 10;
intent.putExtra("entry_id", entryId);
```

then in the resultant Activity

First i tried this:

```
entry_id = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("entry_id");
```

it always gives me the default value `0`

But i changed to this:

```
entry_id = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("entry_id", 1);
```

it gives the correct value (10).

why is it so?

Comment: define constants for your intent extras name. That will avoid you spelling errors like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chanage  `entry_Id` to `entry_id` in your first case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `entry_id = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("entry_Id", 1);`

The change is use of `I` in `id`. It's capital in your get()

The reason is key is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You should use `entry_id` instead of `entry_Id`